# Setting up deep linking in a [NuxtJS capacitor vue] app

Tags: ios, vue.js, nuxt.js, capacitor, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to get deep linking setup in the app I'm working on. I have Firebase Dynamic Link that takes me to the app store page but it will not open the app in local development for ios.

I would like to get this link to open the app if a user has it installed. I seem to have no luck in finding documentation that uses nuxt and capacitor with firebase dynamic links. I have been seeing a lot of swift code for dynamic linking but I am not sure if we can use the swift code since it is being generated by capacitor. I have gone through all the xcode settings to allow for deep links.

Edit: The app opens up currently but I am now confused in how to catch the dynamic links to use for routing.